# Scrambling HTML / CSS issue seems unexplainable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, nginx

I've recently switched over a rails app to a new server. For some reason, search results are *sometimes* scrambled. They look like this:

[image: scrambled results]

But they should look like this:

[image: proper results]

When I check in firebug, it seems that the wrapper div is not being parsed correctly, and so instead of a bunch of nodes wrapped in an `<a>` tag, the nodes are flat in the collection.

[image: firebug issues]

This happens on chrome and firefox, windows and linux, and on different computers. There don't seem to be any CSS or HTML validation errors. I get no problem on my local development server, only in production.

What's odd is that when I view an offending page in Firefox, click `View > Source`, copy the HTML into a blank document and then open it, it comes out looking fine. I also don't seem to have this problem if I just fetch the page with `curl`.

The site is accessible at http://50.57.76.99. You might need to make a couple of searches to get the problematic result. Any ideas? I'm totally baffled!

Comment: I could not repeat your bug, from different OSes and browsers. Are your using some kind of proxy on your network maybe?

Comment: Can't replicate it in FF. But from screen seems like you don't clear your floats correctly.

Comment: One thing I would say is that your main [a] anchor element that is used to wrap all of these pieces of info in each main listing, is an inline element, and as such shouldn't really be used to wrap all of those [div]'s (block level elements). 

I realise this isn't necessarily an answer to your problem, but maybe optimising this so that the anchor constains only proper elements such as img, strong, em span etc. may well help the situation and let you see the wood for the trees.

Comment: Could you post the Ruby code you use to generate and display the search results? This might hold the key to your issues. Also, it may be something to do with the data you are extracting from your database and displaying on your page (is it definately coming through as expected)? As some searches result in pages being broken on almost every refresh.

Comment: Looking at the image above it would appear that one of the property tiles (4th one) has lost it's styling and therefore messing with the whole layout. Is there anything special about the listing which has no styling?

Comment: I have seen this before with FireBug, but I cannot recall how/what was the problem and how I fixed it. :( Try running the output of your page using W3C's html validator and fix any errors/warnings you see and try your code out again? Also try out the most "loose/lenient" DOCTYPE (i.e. not the XHTML variety) and see if you get the same problem; or check that all the tags inside the `<a>` are allowed by whatever DOCTYPE you are using (for example, a `<p>` should not have embedded `<p>`) etc.

Comment: I've sorted it out - see my answer. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to avoid the issue.

If I don't wrap the whole item an `<a>` tag, the problem disappears. Obviously I'd rather have the whole item be a link, but just the image is okay for now. I think another solution would be to swap the `<div>` tags for `<span>` tags as suggested, but this quick-fix seemed to do fine.

Still seems quite bizarre though, as it was seemingly arbitrary when it breaks. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want the whole listing clickable, try changing the `a` to `display:block;` and then wrapping the `div` or attach an event via `js` or `jquery`.